# Is it possible to \include a .TeX file compiled from .Rnw?

Tags: knitr

I have a document with this structure: `main.TeX` which (ideally) includes `bodytext.TeX` compiled with `knitr` from `bodytext.Rnw`.

I say ideally because apparently it is not that simple. I noted that `knitr` adds lines to the preamble of the compiled `.TeX`. Then in my case, when the `.TeX` (without a preamble) is included into another document,  compiling `main.TeX` will result in all sort of errors.

Is it possible to include a `.TeX` compiled from a `.Rnw` then?

Comment: Can you show us an example of the `.tex` files? By the way, have you seen [When should I use `\input` vs. `\include`?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/246)

Comment: Try to set the `xlab` and `ylab` in `plot`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the `main.tex` to be the `main.Rnw`, then you will be able to correctly include the `include.Rnw`:

`main.Rnw`:

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX

\documentclass[final,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

<<include=FALSE>>=
  opts_chunk$set(fig.width=8, fig.height=4, fig.pos='htb', out.width='\\textwidth')
@

\begin{document}
<<child-demo, child='include.Rnw'>>=
@
\end{document}
```

`include.Rnw`:

```
% !TeX root = main.Rnw
% !Rnw weave = knitr
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX

Let's plot the spectrum of $Na$:

<<'na', dev='tikz', fig.cap='Spectrum of $Na$', echo=FALSE>>=
  plot(c(1:10))
@
```

---

Or, you can manually `knit` the desired `Rnw` which **didn't** have preamble, but then you'll need to include additional generated lines in you `main.tex`. Which I won't recommend to do.

Comment: Still then I have problems using `dev='tikz'` for plots built in `include.RnW` on data loaded in `main.RnW`. I get  `Warning in file(filename, mode) :
  cannot open file '/my/path/myplot-tikzDictionary': No such file or directory
% !TeX root = main.Rnw
% !Rnw weave = knitr
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX` when I try to use `tikz` but not when I don't specify the option.

Comment: @Francesco: Can you share a MWE for this?

Comment: I edited the question with a MWE

Comment: The problem with `cannot open ... tikzDictionary` was solved by `quit()` the R session and deleting the cache. I still have an issue with `pgfplotstable`. I posted another question [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142919/clash-between-kintr-tikz-and-pgfplotstable)