# Clash between knitr, tikzDevice and pgfplotstable

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable, knitr, tikzdevice

I use `knitr` to compile a document composed of two `.Rnw`. Please considered the following examples from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/142350/is-it-possible-to-include-a-tex-file-compiled-from-rnw/142355#142355)

`main.Rnw`

```
% !Rnw weave = knitr
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX

\documentclass[final,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
% \usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

<<include=FALSE>>=
  opts_chunk$set(concordance=TRUE, fig.width='8', fig.height='4', fig.pos='htb', out.width='\\textwidth')
@

\begin{document}
<<child-demo, child='include.Rnw', eval=TRUE>>=
@
\end{document}
```

and `include.Rnw`

```
% !TeX root = main.Rnw
% !Rnw weave = knitr
% !TeX program = pdfLaTeX

Let's plot the spectrum of $Na$:

<<'na', dev='tikz', fig.cap='Spectrum of $Na$', echo=FALSE>>=
  plot(c(1:10))
@
```

I have noticed that uncommenting the line `\usepackage{pgfplotstable}` the pdf produced by the `tikzDevice` is of size 0.

This is the verbose output of the `R` console while knitting when loading the `pgfplotstable`, as you can see there's no error message, still the `.pdf` file (but not the `.tikz`) produce is of size 0.

```
> > options(STERM='iESS', str.dendrogram.last="'", editor='emacsclient', show.error.locations=TRUE)
> .ess_weave(knit, "/my/path/main.Rnw")
Loading required package: knitr


processing file: /my/path/main.Rnw
  |.............                                                    |  20%
  ordinary text without R code

  |..........................                                       |  40%
label: unnamed-chunk-1 (with options) 
List of 1
 $ include: logi FALSE

  |.......................................                          |  60%
  ordinary text without R code

  |....................................................             |  80%
label: child-demo (with options) 
List of 2
 $ child: chr "include.Rnw"
 $ eval : logi TRUE



processing file: /my/path/include.Rnw
  |......................                                           |  33%
  ordinary text without R code

  |...........................................                      |  67%
label: na (with options) 
List of 3
 $ dev    : chr "tikz"
 $ fig.cap: chr "Spectrum of $Na$"
 $ echo   : logi FALSE

Warning: 'mode(width)' and 'mode(height)' differ between new and previous
     ==> NOT changing 'width' & 'height'
Creating new TikZ metrics dictionary in:
    include-tikzDictionary
  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


  |.................................................................| 100%
  ordinary text without R code


output file: main.tex

[1] "main.tex"
```

And here the last part (too long to post all) of `na.log` from generating the picture (in the rest of the document I couldn't find any error):

```
Package pgfplots Warning: running in backwards compatibility mode (unsuitable t
ick labels; missing features). Consider writing \pgfplotsset{compat=1.9} into y
our preamble.
 on input line 33.


Overfull \hbox (99.38345pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 124--125
[][] 
 []

(./na.aux) ) 
Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 20223 strings out of 493311
 479203 string characters out of 6137849
 631627 words of memory out of 5000000
 23277 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+600000
 4702 words of font info for 16 fonts, out of 8000000 for 9000
 957 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 65i,7n,84p,700b,609s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,80000s

No pages of output.
PDF statistics:
 3 PDF objects out of 1000 (max. 8388607)
 3 compressed objects within 1 object stream
 0 named destinations out of 1000 (max. 500000)
 13 words of extra memory for PDF output out of 10000 (max. 10000000)
```

Is it possible to use `pgfplotstable` along with the `tikzDevice`?

Comment: Looks like this is due to including `pgfplotstable` after the `preview` package in `na.tikz` in `figure` folder. But, currently, I have no idea how to fix this.

Comment: `pgfplotstable` a such should be harmless... but it includes `pgfplots`, which, in turn, includes `tikz`. Does it make a difference if you include one of `tikz` or `pgfplots` instead of `pgfplotstable`? And: what is the error message? Typically, a result of size 0 means "error" and errors are always indicated by error messages.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger I couldn't find any error message in the R log (I added it to the question). I tried including `tikz` and `pgfplots` instead of `pgfplotstable`: with `tikz` the pdf of the figure is correctly produced but with `pgfplots` the figure pdf has still size 0.

Comment: I did not mean the `R` log, I meant the log produced by `pdflatex`. It is probably available as `main.log` or something like that

Comment: I do not know the answer yet, but first you need to fix a couple of mistakes in the examples you referenced: http://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/142355/revisions There should be a `figure/na.log` file, which you can open and see what is wrong there.

Comment: I added the last part of the na.log. @Yihui your fix to the MWE produces this error to me: `Error in replayPlot(x) (from #91) : invalid graphics state`

Comment: Well, please try your best to be consistent about what you really did and what you posted here. Apparently you were compiling a different `include.Rnw`: you used the chunk option `dev.args=list(pointsize = 90)` there, which is probably way too big for an R graphics device (the default point size is 12). Is there a reason for such a big point size?

Comment: No, sorry no reason. I was trying to tweak the values to get different results. Should I post the log with no pointsize declaration in the chunk?

Comment: OK, edited `R` log.